# Скачивание и сохранения файла / Android

Tags: android, файлы, sd

День добрый. Подскажите, как можно реализовать Скачивание и сохранение файла в память устройства или если есть SD карта то на неё.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если надо через **HTTP**, то вот так:

```
public void saveUrl(final String filename, final String urlString)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
        fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
        if (fout != null) {
            fout.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Затем:

```
try{
    saveUrl(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "...", "...");
}
catch(Exception e){
    //Обработайте ошибку
}
```

[getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()) вернет то, что производитель телефона назвал "внешним хранителем" (external storage).
Для проверки доступности карты памяти, используйте [getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState()).

P.S. Не забудьте добавить в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Использование AsyncTask и показ прогресс скачивание в диалог боксе.**

Данный метод разрешает выполнение процессы в фоновом режиме.

Пример:

```
// declare the dialog as a member field of your activity
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

// instantiate it within the onCreate method
mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
mProgressDialog.setMessage("A message");
mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

// execute this when the downloader must be fired
final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(YourActivity.this);
downloadTask.execute("the url to the file you want to download");

mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        downloadTask.cancel(true);
    }
});

AsyncTask выглядит следующим образом:
// usually, subclasses of AsyncTask are declared inside the activity class.
// that way, you can easily modify the UI thread from here
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private Context context;
    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    public DownloadTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        InputStream input = null;
        OutputStream output = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            // expect HTTP 200 OK, so we don't mistakenly save error report
            // instead of the file
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }

            // this will be useful to display download percentage
            // might be -1: server did not report the length
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file_name.extension");

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                // allow canceling with back button
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null)
                    output.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }

            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Метод `doInBackground` всегда работает в фоновом режиме. Вы не должны делать какие-либо операции связанные с интерфейсом программы. Для этого есть `onProgressUpdate` и `onPreExecute`.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    // take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user 
    // presses the power button during download
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
         getClass().getName());
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    mWakeLock.release();
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    if (result != null)
        Toast.makeText(context,"Download error: "+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(context,"File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Еще не забудьте добавить в AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Еще есть и [другие методы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/1330787), но мне вышеупомянутый понравился.