# Android Нет доступа к внешней micro SD карте

Tags: android, path, sd

Доброго времени суток. В телефон вставлена micro SD-карта Transcend 8GB. Как **корректно** получить к ней путь, по которому можно обратиться для записи? Не могу получить доступ к ней на запись. Подключился по ADB к компьютеру и нашёл две директории с содержимым SD-карты: `/storage/2067-15E4` и `/mnt/m_external_sd`, и при попытке записать что-то в эти директории (к примеру, создать в них файл) вылетает исключение:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
    at.....
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission Denied)
    at.....
```

Вот это `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` возвращает мне только путь к внутренней SD-карте. Нужен путь к внешней. Подскажите, как получить полный доступ (`rwd`) к SD-карте.

Comment: getExternalFilesDir("")

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508172/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-android?rq=1). 
А вы добавили в манифест `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` ?

Если телефон версии 6.0 и выше то почитайте о  [runtime permission](https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/)
(после ознакомления, советую ознакомиться с библиотекой [PermissionUtil](https://github.com/Euzee/permissionUtil)).